# JSON - HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed

Tags: android

I have below code in Android:

```
private void submit(JSONObject json) throws JSONException{
        String urlString = "...";

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);

        try {
            httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", json.toString());

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            if(response != null)
            {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Result: " + sb.toString());
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

But I got this error in logcat:

> Result:  Bad Request
>
> ### Bad
>   Request
>
> ---
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "form": {
        "sixthQuestionAnswer": "Snack/food",
        "ninthQuestionAnswer": "Yes , Rendy O/$ , 100 100",
        "fifthQuestionBudgetAnswer": "Will be",
        "thirdQuestionAnswer": "Several times (2–5x)",
        "secondQuestionAnswer": "No, reasons:",
        "fourthQuestionAnswer": "Very lucky",
        "secondQuestionSuggestionAnswer": "No answer",
        "tenthQuestionAnswer": "No choice",
        "firstQuestionAnswer": "Satisfied , Dissatisfied",
        "fifthQuestionAnswer": "7–12 kgs , Will be",
        "eighthQuestionAnswer": "Yes , Q2 , Y",
        "seventhQuestionAnswer": "1–5,000"
    },
    "ID": "RRR1"
}
```

Can anyone advise what is going on?

Comment: can i see ur **json** and **logcat** ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you send the json in a HTTP header? 
You should send it over in the request body (but I don't know what the web service expects and where does it expect the data).

Comment: Actually I am following this example http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/ but the difference is he put the JSON (set to header) to JSONArray again and set it to parameter, while I am not.

Comment: Hi Axarydax, does put the json to HTTPPost entity means that I put it to request body?

Answer (score 0):

I only need to use this:

```
URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(), "utf-8");
```

and decode the JSON back in web service.